# Lua Script for Controlling WASD Keys via Mouse Movement

Tags: lua, mouse

I need a **lua script** that allows me to **press keys** ("W", "A", "S", "D") **through moving my mouse** in certain direction.

For example:

I am moving mouse up by x pixels ---> Key "W" is being used for for y ms.

And so on analogically for the other mouse movements.

Comment: Mouse movements do not generate events in LGS/GHUB, so you should first generate an event to start the script.  For example, you press Middle mouse button to start the script, then move your mouse to produce WASD, then release Middle mouse button or press Middle mouse button again or press Left mouse button or anything else to stop the script (and be able to handle another events).  What buttons do you want to use as enter/exit the script?

Comment: As I understood, when the middle mouse button was used, there is no need for holding it during the script?

If so, this is what I mean this script to do:

1. Activate the script by clicking the middle mouse button or NumLock key
2. When the script starts, the mouse movements analogically translate into WASD keys being used (I want an option in the script to change the value of how much time the key is being used. Example: if the mouse moves left by x pixel/s --> "A" key is being used for y ms)
3. When I want to stop the script, I use the same key.
**Thank you, I appreciate your help.**

Comment: `"A" key is being used for y ms` - key is pressed for y ms and then released?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. I want to control (and change the value in script if I need to) how much time in ms the key is being pressed and then relased.

Comment: To be more correct: [1. Mouse is being moved by x pixels in for example left (x can be later changed in script if needed) | 2. key (if mouse moves left, then "A") works for y ms (y can be later changed in script if needed) and then is being relased] and so on for another directions analogically. Also if I move mouse for example x pixels left and z pixels up, the buttons "A" and "W" are being pressed for y ms and v ms (by this I mean the values for moving 1 pixel left and 1 pixel up are not the same and can be changed later separately for left: ("A"), up ("W"), and so on for ("S") and ("D").

Comment: Can WASD be pressed simultaneously?  What is the minimum interval between two key press of the same key?

Comment: Can WASD be pressed simultaneously? - Well, the mouse movement manages if it can be. I guess all WASD buttons cannot be pressed at the same time, because mouse movement guides the buttons. Mouse can direct it in x and y axis, so 2 buttons can be used at the same time.

Comment: What is the minimum interval between two key press of the same key? - Mouse movement sets interval between the same key being pressed. If script detects that mouse cursor has been moved by x pixels, then the key is being used again for y amount of time as I wrote previously. 
And I guess there is no delay between the same key being pressed again. If mouse pointer moves by x pixels, then button is being pressed for y ms. If 2x pixels, then 2y ms.

Comment: I have removed the [tag:logitech] related tags since I suspect the answer will not need curtailing to that detail, and because it wasn't mentioned in the question body as being an important detail. Feel free to add them back with an explanation if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
-- turn script on  - click middle mouse button while NumLock LED is ON
-- turn script off - click middle mouse button

--------------------------------------------------------------------
--  PARAMETERS
--------------------------------------------------------------------

local distance_horiz  = 20  -- x, pixels
local distance_vert   = 25  -- x, pixels
local key_press_delay = 30  -- y, ms

local screen_width  = 1920   --  set your game screen resolution here
local screen_height = 1080

--------------------------------------------------------------------

local active

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3 then  -- Middle mouse button
      active = not active and IsKeyLockOn"NumLock"
      if active then
         local horiz, vert, horiz_key, vert_key, horiz_key_tm, vert_key_tm = 0, 0
         local prev_MMB = true
         repeat
            local prev_x, prev_y = math.floor(screen_width/2), math.floor(screen_height/2)
            local x = math.floor(prev_x * (2^16-1) / (screen_width-1) + 0.5)
            local y = math.floor(prev_y * (2^16-1) / (screen_height-1) + 0.5)
            MoveMouseTo(x, y)
            Sleep(10)
            local MMB = IsMouseButtonPressed(2)
            local exit = MMB and not prev_MMB
            prev_MMB = MMB
            x, y = GetMousePosition()
            x = math.floor((x + (0.5 + 2^-16)) * (screen_width-1) / (2^16-1))
            y = math.floor((y + (0.5 + 2^-16)) * (screen_height-1) / (2^16-1))
            horiz, vert = horiz + x - prev_x, vert + y - prev_y
            local tm = GetRunningTime()
            -- horiz
            if tm >= (horiz_key_tm or 0) then
               if math.abs(horiz) >= distance_horiz then
                  local new_key
                  if horiz > 0 then
                     horiz, new_key = horiz - distance_horiz, "D"
                  else
                     horiz, new_key = horiz + distance_horiz, "A"
                  end
                  if new_key ~= horiz_key then
                     if horiz_key then
                        ReleaseKey(horiz_key)
                     end
                     PressKey(new_key)
                  end
                  horiz_key, horiz_key_tm = new_key, (horiz_key_tm or tm) + key_press_delay
               elseif horiz_key then
                  ReleaseKey(horiz_key)
                  horiz_key, horiz_key_tm = nil
               end
            end
            -- vert
            if tm >= (vert_key_tm or 0) then
               if math.abs(vert) >= distance_vert then
                  local new_key
                  if vert > 0 then
                     vert, new_key = vert - distance_vert, "S"
                  else
                     vert, new_key = vert + distance_vert, "W"
                  end
                  if new_key ~= vert_key then
                     if vert_key then
                        ReleaseKey(vert_key)
                     end
                     PressKey(new_key)
                  end
                  vert_key, vert_key_tm = new_key, (vert_key_tm or tm) + key_press_delay
               elseif vert_key then
                  ReleaseKey(vert_key)
                  vert_key, vert_key_tm = nil
               end
            end
         until exit
         if vert_key then
            ReleaseKey(vert_key)
         end
         if horiz_key then
            ReleaseKey(horiz_key)
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: It makes mouse cursor movements being translated into WASD keys. Also, I can change values if needed.

However, when I move my mouse for example right side of the screen, and when I run out of space on my computer screen, I have to move it back to the middle of the screen. Moving my mouse cursor back causes pressing "A" button and "D" button for the same amount of time. What it means is that the object moves (for example) 5 steps right, and it goes back 5 steps left. The same thing happens for "W" and "S" buttons.

Comment: Could you please make the mouse cursor somehow "froze" in the middle of the screen while I pressed middle mouse button, and at the same time be able to make mouse movements that cause WASD keys to be pressed as it works on your script?

Thanks.

Comment: @FlysAreAttackingMe - Answer updated.

Comment: Script works and the issue was fixed.

Thank you very much for your help. 

I have only noticed a problem when I set screen resolution for my screen ("W" button keeps being used while mouse is not being moved) but when I set your recommended resolution everything works at best, so no need to fix it.

The issue probably occurs at my device individualy, however it works well when I set 1920 x 1080 resolution in script.

Again, thank you for your time and help.

Comment: What's your device resolution?  Does the game run in the native screen resolution or in the different one (in the game video options)?

Comment: `"W" button keeps being used while mouse is not being moved` - this means screen height in the script does not match the game screen height (in the fullscreen mode, it does not mean game window height).

Comment: Now everything works as it should, even when I do not have fullscreen mode turned on. But thanks for advice. I will follow it if something gone wrong with the buttons while not moving the mouse.